# moving application from nginx to nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx

I have a small web application(html,css,javascript,jquery and angularjs) which runs on nginx server.I've been asked to move it from nginx to nodejs server.What does this mean?And how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a javascript runtime engine you can install on your computer to execute javascript code outside of the browser.

Nginx is a webserver, and Exprpess is a simple library for creating a webserver with Node. Here's [a quick starter on that](http://mfranc.com/node-js/node-js-simple-web-server-with-express/).

So all you have to do is serve the `dist` generated from angualar with the node + expresss webserver instead of the Nginx one.

[This should be helpful enough](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/) to get you started on creating the API.

Answer (score 0):

Install Node, Npm.
using npm install http-server

```
npm install http-server -g
```

move to that directory where your all files (html,css,javascript,jquery and angularjs) present. Run the command

```
http-server -p 3000
```

It will run you application using node on http://localhost:3000

Comment: i installed nodejs..am i supposed to just type in these codes in the command prompt?and aftr typing "npm install http-server -g" how do i move into the directory?as in where or how shud i type in d path?I'm sorry i 'm under a training programme before entry into a company and i'm not from a computer science background.

Answer (score -3):

It means the person who asked you to do that has clearly no idea about both nginx and nodejs. They are compatible.

This will teach you how to make a simple HTTP server:

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: Move the application built so far from Nginx to Node.js Server.
Connect your application to the postgresql database built in Problem Statement 6.
Write APIs (HTTP requests) in Express.js to call the queries built for Problem
Statement 6 and get the results.
Build “Problem Statement 7” page which calls the above mentioned APIs and
displays the results on the page.          This is what i've been assigned to do.I dont know anything about what nodejs ,express.js or the api thing is or how to connect ,y html files to a database ...can you provide me with links that can teach me all this?

Comment: @sidewinder How exactly are they incompatible, this is false information. It is actually quite common to use an Nginx webserver as a reverse proxy for node webservers.

Comment: How does "This will teach you how to make a simple HTTP server" answer the question?  This site focuses on providing *useful* answers **to the entire community**, not just the initial asker.  Link only Questions and Answers are ***both*** mentioned as things not to do in the [help].  Cleanup and improvement of questions and answers is a common thing here, and important to making questions and answers clear and easy to find.  You are certainly welcome to ignore the suggestions for improvements, but shouldn't be surprised by the negative reputation points as a result.

Comment: If he's serving static files with nginx and he asks how to do it with node, the answer is to make an HTTP server. Node changes a lot over time, and many pieces of code posted here worked for older versions but they don't work anymore because modules change, so the obvious solution is to provide a link because as modules change so does documentation. Don't get me wrong, I am open to useful criticism, but I fail to see the usefulness of yours.